# Text input fields in iMacros

Tags: imacros

I want to fill out a text field in an AJAX form.

The AJAX nature of the form prevents me from doing something like this...

```
TAG TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=Listing ATTR=NAME:Name CONTENT={{!COL1}}
```

Instead, in order to position the cursor in the field itself, I am needing to do something like the following...

```
CLICK X=411 Y=434
```

Also, I'm using the Firefox version so Direct Screen doesn't work because `DS` is only supported in Explorer. For example,

```
DS CMD=CLICK X=411 Y=434
```

doesn't work. If it did, then I would try something like:

```
DS CMD=CLICK X=411 Y=434 CONTENT={{!COL1}}
```

But, as mentioned, `DS` doesn't work in Firefox.

I need to emulate the action of actually typing the keys on the keyboard.

So how would I do this and actually insert data into the field?

Comment: If you're using 'iMacros' for Firefox, you can emulate actions of actually typing the keyboard keys by means of the [`EVENT` command](http://wiki.imacros.net/EVENT).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this (and an associated dialog handler issue) [by using the EVENT recording mode](http://wiki.imacros.net/EVENT).

Procedure:

1. Open #Current.iim
2. <kbd>Rec</kbd>
3. <kbd>Record options</kbd>
4. <kbd>Experimental event recording mode</kbd> (select this radio button option from popup/dialog menu)

The resulting code was as follows:

#Current.iim

```
VERSION BUILD=8970419 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://console.developers.google.com/project
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#projects-create" BUTTON=0
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#p6n-project-name-text" CHARS="My Project"
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#p6n-project-creation-dialog-ok-button>BUTTON" BUTTON=0
```